# Problemas al eliminar registros en postgres 8.4.20 desde PHP

Tags: php, postgresql

Deseo eliminar registros de dos tablas que se encuentran relacionadas, para ello debo eliminar primero el registro insertado en la tabla archivo_x_act_proceso y luego el registro en la tabla  actuacionesxproceso, estoy haciéndolo en el orden indicado y para asegurarme que todo ha salido bien he usado transacciones, pero obtengo el siguiente error.

[image: Error al borrar]

utilizo el siguiente código en PHP para ejecutar el borrado de los registros en las dos tablas, uso unos print() para rastrear el problema:

```
try {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->beginTransaction();

        $sql_before = " DELETE FROM archivo_x_act_proceso WHERE axp_actproceso = ? ";
        $q_before = $pdo->prepare($sql_before);
        $q_before->execute(array($_POST['actuacion']));
        
        if (!$q_before) {
            print('TRANSACCION BEFORE FALLA');
            echo Mensajes::$transactFail;
            $pdo->rollBack();
        } else {
            print('TRANSACCION BEFORE ENTRA');
            $sql = " DELETE FROM actuacionesxproceso WHERE axp_id = ? ";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($_POST['axp_id']));
            if (!$q) {
                print('TRANSACCION AFTER FALLA');
                echo Mensajes::$transactFail;
                $pdo->rollBack();
            } else {
                $pdo->commit();
                echo Mensajes::$transactOK;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo Mensajes::$transactFail . $e->getMessage();
        $pdo->rollBack();
    } finally {
        Database::disconnect();
    }
```

Estas son mis dos tablas que se encuentran involucradas en el error:

```
CREATE TABLE actuacionesxproceso(
    axp_fecha date,
    axp_actuacion integer,
    axp_proceso integer,
    axp_observacion character varying(455),
    axp_id integer PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE archivo_x_act_proceso(
    axp_actproceso integer NOT NULL,
    axp_archivo character varying(50) NOT NULL,
    axp_archivo_ruta character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(axp_actproceso) REFERENCES actuacionesxproceso (axp_id));
```

Comment: no puedes eliminar una clave externa si aun hace referencia a otra debes modificarlo para que elimine en cascada te inviteo a ver la documentacion [constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/ddl-constraints.html)

Comment: Eso lo entiendo y por eso lo explico detalladamente, primero borro el registro de la tabla archivo_x_act_proceso y luego el de la tabla actuacionesxproceso, lo hago en el orden exacto.

Comment: Por algún motivo el `DELETE` está ocurriendo antes en la tabla `actuacionesxproceso`, observa que tienes el código basado en `if` y nada te asegura que un cierto bloque que esperas ocurra antes ocurre después. De todos modos este tipo de cosas se resuelven mejor en la misma base de datos, definiendo para este caso una restricción `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Así, cuando un registro se borre en su tabla se borrarán los registros dependientes en las tablas referenciadas.